# Transition to a new basis with rotation of one of the axes

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-geometry

The lengths of the basis vectors e1 and e2 of the general Cartesian coordinate system on the plane are equal to 4 and 2, respectively, and the angle between the basis vectors is 120°. Relative to this coordinate system, the vertices of the triangle A(-2,2), B(-2,-1), C(-1,0) are specified. Find the lengths of the sides and angles of the triangle.

There is an answer |AB| = 6, |AC| = 4√3, |VS| = 2√3, A = 30°, B = 90°, C = 60°. How to reach it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, among other things, it is not related to the software Mathematica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write the given base in an orthonormal base like:

```
base = {{4, 0}, 2 {-Sin[30 Degree], Cos[30 Degree]}};
```

Then the vertices are:

```
{a, b, c} = {{-2, 2}, {-2, -1}, {-1, 0}} . base;
```

And side the lengths and angles:

```
Norm /@ {a - b, b - c, c - a}

{6, 2 Sqrt[3], 4 Sqrt[3]}

N[VectorAngle[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ {{a - b, a - c}, {b - a, 
     b - c}, {c - a, c - b}}]/Degree 

{30., 90., 60.}
```